# Draytek VPN stuck on Authentica IKEv2 EAP

Tags: vpn, ipsec, draytek

I've set up the following configurations on my draytek vigor 2926:

[IPsec general setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkfe8.png)

and the remote dial-in user:

[remote dial-in user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAcMd.png)

I get the following error: unknown error
Status in Smartclient: Authenticating

I've removed quite a lot of security to see if anything was blocking it, but it still doesn't work.

```
[2023-10-17 14:06:44]  **   IP Address {XXX.drayddns.com}
[2023-10-17 14:06:44]  **   User Name {testuser}
[2023-10-17 14:06:44]  **   Status: Connect <IKEv2 EAP>
[2023-10-17 14:06:44]  **   Status: Connecting...
[2023-10-17 14:06:44]  **   Status: Open port
[2023-10-17 14:06:44]  **   Status: Port opened
[2023-10-17 14:06:44]  **   Status: Dialing...
[2023-10-17 14:06:45]  **   Status: Device connected
[2023-10-17 14:06:45]  **   Status: All devices connected
[2023-10-17 14:06:45]  **   Status: Authenticate
[2023-10-17 14:06:51]  **   {  ERROR  } Unknown error.
[2023-10-17 14:06:51]  **   Status: No connection
[2023-10-17 14:06:51]  **   Status: Connection failed
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a broken router, this config works on other Draytek routers.